# How to hide HTML5 dividers when if at least 1 selected item has a custom attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I have a form with multiple HTML checkboxes. I want to hide some dividers only if **at least one** checked checkbox have a custom HTML5 attribute called "terminator". Otherwise I would want to show the dividers.

I tried to accomplish this by using the `change()` event to check if one has the `terminator` attribute.

Here is what I have done.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) {

    var className = 'terminated_' + getContronId($(this).attr('name'));

    var existingElements = $('#survey-optional-controls').val().split('|') || [];


    //Hide all groups that have the class equal to className
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){

        if( $(this).data('terminator') ){
            hideControls($(this), existingElements, className);
        }

    } else {

        showControls(existingElements, className);

    }

}).change();
```

The function `hideControls` will hide the desire inputs. The function `showControls` will display the desired inputs if any are hidden.

My code kinda works, but has one problem that I can't figure out a solution to. The problem happens after checking a box that has the `terminator` attribute and checking a box that does NOT have the `terminator` attribute, and then "un-checking" a box that does NOT have the `terminator` attribute.

When first checking the box with the `terminator` attribute the dividers hide as expected.

Then when un-checking a box that does not have a `terminator` attribute it shows dividers that should be hidden with appear since I still have 1 checked box with the `terminator` attribute.

How can I fix this problem?

I created this [jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8yf0v3xt/1/) to show the code and the problem in action. You can re-create the problem by jumping into the "1:b) More Questions" section on the jFiddle, then check the "Red" box and then the "Green - Terminator" box, and finally unchecking the "Red" box. You will see how the dividers below will appear where they should be hidden since "Green - terminator" is still checked"

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle to show the issue?

Comment: @rahul I just created one. you can find it on this link https://jsfiddle.net/8yf0v3xt/1/  .. You can created the problem if you go to the section "1:b) More Questions" then check the "Red" box and then the "Green - Terminator" box and finally unchecking the "Red" box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking for the "checked" status of the checkbox with data-terminator attribute set on each change.

Something like

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) {
  var className = 'terminated_' + getContronId($(this).attr('name'));
  var existingElements = $('#survey-optional-controls').val().split('|') || [];

  var isTerminatorChecked = $("input:checkbox[data-terminator='Yes']").is(":checked");

  //Hide all groups that have the class equal to className
  if (isTerminatorChecked) {
    hideControls($(this), existingElements, className);
  } else {
    showControls(existingElements, className);
  }
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulsadasivan/8yf0v3xt/9/)

Comment: This code indeed worked. Would you mind explaining why this code worked? what is the problem with using $(this) ?

Comment: Every time when you check a checkbox, you need to find whether the element with 'data-terminator' is checked or not, irrespective of 'this.checked'

Comment: isn't that what $(this).data('terminator') do?

Comment: This code works but is an overkill @DavidDomain's code is the better answer

Comment: If there are multiple elements with data-terminator set as "true" this will work.

Comment: How to hide HTML5 dividers when if **at least 1 selected item has a custom attribute**?

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that `showControls` will only get invoked when the checkbox with the `data-terminator` attribute gets unchecked,

change this :

```
...

} else {
    showControls(existingElements, className);
}
```

to

```
...

} else if ($(this).is("[data-terminator]")) {
    showControls(existingElements, className);
}
```

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8yf0v3xt/10/

Comment: @Nayish - Thank you, that is even cleaner. ;-)

Comment: Will this work, if there are multiple elements with 'data-terminator' attribute?

Comment: @rahul - Then you would have to make sure that all of them are either checked or unchecked. If this is what you want.

Answer (score -2):

the code below said 'If any input that have the type `checkbox` is changing'

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) { /*hide*/ }
else { /*show*/}
```

when you uncheck the "red" checkbox `this`="red", and red is not checked so... it automatically go to the else statment which in to show divider

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not sure that I follow you here. How would I use ID? if you look at my html code in the fiddler each checkbox has an ID.

Comment: when the div is hidden, when you un-check on a non-terminated checkbox,  the if statment will fail b/c the current checkbox is `not('checked')` so your showControls run.  do you understand?

Comment: not really I am not following you still. do you mind update the fiddle?

Comment: I try to write it as simple as possible, please see edited answer.